# How do you extend a bounded generic type to another bounded generic type?

Tags: java, generics

The offending line is:

```
public class InputField<W extends WidgetInterface>
                             extends InputFieldArray<W extends WidgetInterface>
```

As you can see, i am trying to extend a generic type (`InputFieldArray`) to another generic type (`InputField`).  The generic type parameter `W` is bounded in both cases to be an implementation of the `WidgetInterface` interface.

If I do this, the compiler complains that it was expecting a `>` after the second `W`.  OK, maybe the compiler is clever enough that I can write this:

```
public class InputField<W extends WidgetInterface> extends InputFieldArray<W>
```

If I do this, however, the compiler complains that the second `W` is 'not within its bound'.  What am I getting wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do whatever you're trying to do, without all this generics mess.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `InputFieldArray`?

Comment: Do you want the entire class file?  `InputFieldArray` is declared as `public class InputFieldArray<W extends Component & WidgetInterface> extends JPanel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, it looks like you should do:

```
public class InputField<W extends Component & WidgetInterface>
extends InputFieldArray<W>
```

The compiler error is self-explanatory: without giving `W` upper bounds of `Component` and `WidgetInterface`, it isn't within its bounds as a type argument for `InputFieldArray`.

Your first snippet is simply a syntax error: you only specify the bounds of a type parameter at declaration.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is right to complain.

You have said that the generic parameter to `InputFieldArray` must be a subclass of `Component` **and** `WidgetInterface`.  However, you're trying to declare that `InputField` only takes a parameter that is a `WidgetInterface`.

This can't compile, otherwise someone could create an `InputField` with a generic parameter that wasn't a `Component`.  And that's not consistent with its superclass - type safety would be broken (in that casts would fail at runtime), which undermines the entire point of generics.

You need to apply the same constraints (or stricter) in your subclass:

```
public class InputField<W extends Component & WidgetInterface>
             extends InputFieldArray<W>
```